# aws-amplify authentication login timeout using AUTH angular

Tags: angularjs, federated-identity, aws-amplify

When using Aws-amplify how do i set the user login time out, 
Do i have to create a timeout mechanism with this -> i.e. a custom timeout then just log the user out. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Is this not a feature not sure if this applies. 
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/368

I see the analytics has a session manager with a timeout that is fixed. 
https://github.com/mbahar/aws-amplify/blob/986a9ec4/packages/aws-amplify/src/Analytics/SessionManage.ts#L19

In Auth.ts there is a **user, expires_at**

Credentials.set({ provider, token, identity_id, user, expires_at }

Is there a way to set the time out globally, for an object or specific component requiring the user to verify login information after a timeout?

Is there a design paradigm I am missing?

The application is being developed in Angular.

I have worked with this repository seems to be a clean example of an angular implementation

https://github.com/daikiojm/angular-aws-amplify.git

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing.

My app is in React, but I guess this can be ported to angular easily?

According to this post [When are credentials considered expired?](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/698) I don't think there's a native aws-amplify way to sign out on timeout. Also, it doesn't seem the dev is planning on such feature in the near future.

So my current workaround is to sign out on tab close:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleBeforeunload);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleBeforeunload);
  }

  handleBeforeunload(event) {
    Auth.signOut()
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

However, I've been thinking about replacing the above with `setTimeout clearTimeout` and a `timeoutToken`. I'll update this answer if I manage to do so.